# makes ready sense -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

From the book [Thinking in Java](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/):

> Encapsulation creates new data types by combining characteristics and behaviors. Implementation hiding separates the interface from the implementation by making the details private. This sort of mechanical organization **makes ready sense** to someone with a procedural programming background. But polymorphism deals with decoupling in terms of types.

What does that exactly mean?

Comment: *ready sense* is a noun phrase. Something like *makes obvious sense* or *clearly makes sense*, because you already know it.

Comment: makes sense immediately.  They don't have to study or guess.  The concepts, while perhaps new, will be understood without any effort.

Comment: While understandable, I think it's an odd construction.  The usage usually references something a bit more concrete, like "ready cash" (cash that is available quickly or on hand) and even "ready wit" (a quick wit).  But "makes ready sense" is a bit too verbish for me here.  Perhaps it's a matter of style.  I would have just cut all the fluff and said, *This **is easily understood** by someone with a procedural programming background*.  See [COCA: `ready *noun*`](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=40050331) for the common uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Makes ready sense* means something like *is easily and quickly understood*. In this context it means that someone with a procedural programming background will understand the organization immediately.

*Ready* in this sense means *quick to understand*, or in this case, *quick to be understood*.